# How to get changed items since second-last login?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have got the following two tables:

Table called `reviews`:
(One ID can exist multiple times)
This ID means, that the following REVIEW is made for the user with the id.

[image]

Table called `login_history`:

[image]

How do I get the number of reviews ( one review is represented by its `id` in table `reviews` ) since the second-last login of a user?

## **Example**:

Let's say an user with the `id` 19 logs in. As sonn as he logs in, a new value will be inserted into `login_history`. This will look like `2017-04-05 19:00:00, 19`. Then, a review for him gets edited, and the `modified` value gets changed. If the user then logs out and back in, he should see some kind of message saying: "1 new review(s) got edited since your last login".

The difficult part about this is that a new row gets inserted into `login_history` BEFORE the query will be run, e.g. before the user visits the "New Reviews" page.

How can I get the desired result just by one sql query?

### Edit 1:

Sample data for table `reviews`: https://hastebin.com/uhoyupuvem.sql
Sample data for table `login_history`: https://hastebin.com/ququzequsu.sql

Comment: instead of image can you provide sample data?

Comment: Isn't the image some kind of sample data? :)

Comment: @DirtyDev ... NO, image isn't sample data. If I have to type this to test that... I'll pass and go to answer another question. ;)

Comment: @roetnig I've just edited the post, you can find a SQL dump there. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

Find the last login date (copied from skayp answer):

```
SELECT `for_date`
FROM `login_history`
WHERE `user` = 10
ORDER BY `for_date` DESC
LIMIT 1,1
```

Then use this result as part of the comparision:

```
SELECT * FROM `test`.`reviews` WHERE `modified` > (SELECT `for_date`
FROM `login_history`
WHERE `user` = 10
ORDER BY `for_date` DESC
LIMIT 1,1)
```

So you have all the modifications by this user previous to the second last login.

Comment: I think it should be `WHERE modified > (SELECT` instead of `<`, doesn't it? I wan't all reviews SINCE the second-last login, so everything that got changed AFTER the second-last login

Comment: And furthermore, how can I than count HOW MANY of these reviews (since last login) exist? Something like `COUNT ( ... )`? :)

Comment: Edit: I fixed it:

`SELECT COUNT(*) as numbers FROM info.reviews WHERE modified > (SELECT for_date FROM login_history WHERE user = 10 ORDER BY for_date DESC LIMIT 1,1)`

Comment: @DirtyDev, sorry for the `<` and `>` error.. I was at the end of my work day and was in a hurry ,) And yes, `GOUP BY` and `COUNT()` with the result will give you the number of edits

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `LIMIT` AND `ORDER BY` in the query to select the second latest entry.

```
SELECT `for_date`
FROM `login_history`
WHERE `user` = 10
ORDER BY `for_date` DESC
LIMIT 1,1
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: That returns the second last login of a user. However, I want all reviews that changed since the second last login of a certain user.